# view Scoped Beans are never refreshed inserted as dynamic content

Tags: jsf, primefaces, view-scope, dynamic-content

I got a jsf main.xhtml which leads to a Session Scoped MenuBean.
I'm always on the same site, but I get different Content for it dynamically with an dynamic include.

```
<h:body styleClass="template">
<ui:insert name="metadata" />

<p:layout fullPage="true">

  <ui:include src="#{menuBean.menuToInclude}" />

  <p:layoutUnit position="south" rendered="#{menuBean.menuPosition.equals('top')}" styleClass="footer">
    <ui:include src="/include/footer.jspx" />
  </p:layoutUnit>

  <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerUnit">
    <p:panel id="contentUnit" styleClass="inner_center">
      <ui:include src="#{contentBean.requestSite}" />
    </p:panel>

  </p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
```

this works fine so far. But now my problem is, that the included content site is depending on a view Scoped Bean which is never refreshed, because I never change my view.
Request scope doesn't work because sometimes I need to keep some parameters.
And i can't keep all Beans session scoped, because I need new instances when I change the dynamic content.

Are there any tips?

I'm using JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 5.2

for example, this is a not implemented include site:

```
 <ui:composition  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

        Your Content

</ui: composition>
```

Comment: You can use flash scope combined with request scope and http session..ie, mark the dynamic content bean with request scope. in request scoped bean's prerenderview method keep request parameters in flash scope of facescontext. when dynamic content changes, new instances get created but our required paramters still exists in facescontext's flash scope. Instead of flash scope, i guess you could also use http session to store the request parameters.

Comment: So you are saying it works woth a plain non- primefaces panel and leaving the layout out? (You used PrimeFaces code in the example ajd tagged it PrimeFaces)

Comment: @EvaMariam but isn't request scope pretty bad for the performance? :/ I'm dealing with a large dataset.

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm sorry, I dont get your question. I marked it with primefaces and yes, I work with primefaces. The dynamic content is the ui:include contentBean.requestSite. requestSite has a getter in the session Scoped Bean ContentBean.

Comment: Does the same problem exhibit itself **without** PrimeFaces (so a plain h:panel and **not** using a p:layout). If so, it is in no way PF related.

Comment: If you add a tag, you expliciy state the Problem is caused by using that, a tag is not meant to state something is 'used'. Same for your [mcve]. If a certain tag is in there and it is a real mcve, you state that leaving that tag out makes it work